# Get specific user response in array post values

Tags: php, mysql

I creating a quiz. Everything is working fine but I don't seem to get a specific user response in the process PHP file.

```
<form action="process.php" method="post">

        <?php
        foreach($questions as $id => $question) {
            echo "<div class=\"form-group\">";
            echo "<ol><li><h5 style='font-weight:bolder'> $question</h5>"."</li><ol>";//display the question

            //Display multiple choices
            $randomChoices = $choices[$id];
            $randomChoices = shuffle_assoc($randomChoices);
            foreach ($randomChoices as $key => $values){
                echo '<li style="list-style-type: upper-alpha; font-weight:bolder;"><input required="" type="radio" name="response['.$id.'] id="'.$id.'" value="' .$values.'"/>';
            ?>
                <label for="question-<?php echo($id); ?>"><?php echo($values);?></label></li>
        <?php

            }
                echo("</ul>");
                echo("</div>");
            }
           ?>

        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit Quiz" />
    </form>
```

The above code displays: Thus a quiz.

- Which Ghanaian has ever ascended to the UN General Secretary position?
- A.  President Kuffour
- B. Kofi Anan
- C. Prince Omar
- D. John Dumelo
- Who is the current president of Ghana?
- A. Ata Mills
- B. John Agyekum Kuffour
- C. John Mahama
- D. Nana Addo Danquah Akufo Addo

In the process.php I want to get the choice the user selected 
process.php

I want to get a something like

- - Who is the current president of Ghana?
- A. President Kuffour (**Thus the user's choice**).

But I get something like:

- Who is the current president of Ghana?
- User's choice : President KuffourAta Mills1975 (All the choice
  selected for each questions.

  $question) {
          echo "";
          echo " $question"."";//display the question

  ```
          echo '<li style="list-style-type: upper-alpha; font-weight:bolder;">';
      ?>
          <label for="question-<?php echo($id); ?>"><?php foreach($_POST['response'] as $response){
          echo $response;
          }?></label></li>
  <?php


          echo("</ul>");
          echo("</div>");

      }
     ?>
  ```

When I use

```
<?php foreach($_POST['response'] as $response){
                echo $response;
                }?>
```

It echo's all the user response for all the question. But I want a specific response for every question.

Comment: Please Show us what you get and what do you aspect

Comment: your name field doesn't seem to have closing quotes name="response['.$id.']

Comment: Ok I will do that in the edit of the main page.